# Javascript prevents radio button from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this is pretty simple, but I can't figure out why `#type2` can't be clicked.

```
<input type="radio" id="type1" name="group1" checked>

<input type="radio" id="type2" name="group1">

<input type="text" class="type1">

<input type="text" class="type2" disabled>

<script>

function toggle() {
    if ($('#type1').attr('checked', true)) {
        $('.type1').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.type2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else if ($('#type2').attr('checked', true)) {
        $('.type1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.type2').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    toggle();
});

</script>
```

I can't see what the problem is.  Any help would be fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function toggle() {
    if ($('#type1').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.type2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else if ($('#type2').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.type2').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/z5Wbv/1/

The version of [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) you were using was *setting* `#type1`'s `checked` attribute to true. You can use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is), with the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to determine if a checkbox/radio button is checked.

Answer (score 2):

You're using .attr instead of .prop.

.attr is for attributes, .prop is for properties. Properties = checked, selected, disabled.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

To determine if a checkbox is checked,

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $(elem).prop("checked") )
if ( $(elem).is(":checked") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YUhFw/

Few things that needs to be corrected `:)`

- Check if it is checked using `.is(":checked")`
- Attach it to click event.
- Attach and detach the `disabled` attribute accordingly.

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**code**

```
function toggle() {
    if ($('#type1').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.type2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else if ($('#type2').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.type2').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        toggle();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **not checking** for a condition here.

You are **setting it** `which is always true`..
Try this Instead

```
if ($('#type1').is(':checked')){
```

Also use `.prop()` **instead** of `.attr()` as this is truly not a attribute but a property of a radio Button.
Your code should look like this

```
function toggle() {
    if ($('#type1').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').prop('disabled', false);
        $('.type2').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else if ($('#type2').is(':checked')) {
        $('.type1').prop('disabled', true);
        $('.type2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}
```